# WP7's WebBrowser.NavigateToString() and text encoding

Tags: encoding, browser, windows-phone-7

does anyone know how to load a UTF8-encoded string using WebBrowser.NavigateToString() method? For now I end up with a bunch of mis-displayed characters.

Here's the simple string that won't display correctly:

```
webBrowser.NavigateToString("ąęłóńżźćś");
```

The code file is saved with UTF-8 encoding (with signature).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share some code that fails ? Strings in .NET are internally represented as UTF-16, so I would guess that your conversion to a string from whatever source you have, fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, `NavigateToString()` is expecting a full html document.

Secondly, as you're passing HTML, it's best to pass HTML entities, rather than relying on encodings. Unfortunately, not that many entity codes are actually supported by the browser so you should look at using the numeric unicode values where necessary.
Much like this:

```
webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<html><body><p>&oacute; &#213;</p></body></html>");
```

Comment: Thanks, in my app I use full HTML documents. That was just the example. I'm also aware tehat using HTML entities work. But isn't there any way to just pass a UTF-8-encoded doc to NavigateToString()??

Comment: @Immortal IE7 mobile seems to really struggle with encodings. numeric values is the most reliable solution I've found. :(

Comment: I don't think you're being fair on IE in this particular case. The System.String class can only represent strings using UTF16, so IE assumes that is what the string contains. If you have UTF8 in the form in the question you need to either convert it to a string (i.e. UTF16) first, or use a stream. In the example in the question I don't see a UTF8 string, and neither does IE. What I see is a UTF16 string containing some eastern european letters.

Answer (score 6):

Using `ConvertExtendedASCII` as suggested works, but is very slow. Using a `StringBuilder` instead was (in my case) about **800** times faster:

```
public string FixHtml(string HTML)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] s = HTML.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(c) > 127)
            sb.Append("&#" + Convert.ToInt32(c) + ";");
        else
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this article](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2010/10/25/international-utf-8-characters-in-windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control/). It should help. Shortly speaking, it proposes to use following snippet to convert your string into appropriate format:

```
private static string ConvertExtendedASCII(string HTML)
{
    string retVal = "";
    char[] s = HTML.ToCharArray();

    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(c) > 127)
            retVal += "&#" + Convert.ToInt32(c) + ";";
        else
            retVal += c;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: [It would be better to include a summary of the resource in your answer as well as just a link...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Got it. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the *UTF8* in memory in a byte array then you could try `NavigateToStream` with a `MemoryStream` rather than using `NavigateToString`. You should try to ensure their is a *BOM* on the *UTF8* buffer if you can.

Note that the string in the question is not a *UTF8* string. It is a *UTF16* string with some garbage in it. By placing zeros between the bytes and storing it in a `System.String` you corrupted it.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no NavigateToStream() method on the WP7 platform.

Comment: Ah. That spoils that plan then.